# Installing Microsft Edge in Windows Containers

Tags: installation, microsoft-edge, windows-container

**Context**

I'm trying to create a selenium-standalone windows container so we can run e2e-tests on Microsoft Edge. To do this I need to install Microsoft Edge in the container. Afaik, Microsoft does not publish Edge in any form. They only pre-package Edge with Windows.

Unfortunately Edge isn't pre-packaged in any Windows Container. I verified this by adding: `RUN powershell (Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge).Version` to my `.Dockerfile` which always came up empty regardless of the tag and image.

**Specific question**

What I would like to know is whether someone knows where I can find an installer for Edge that's atleast semi-official. I had no luck finding one so far neither online nor in any package-manager.

**General question**

If you can't answer the question above but do know a different method of installing Microsoft Edge in a Windows Container, please share.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is now a Docker Image with Edge and Edgedriver, the link is at the bottom of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-msedge-msedgedriver?tab=description

"This experimental docker container contains Microsoft Edge (Chromium) and Microsoft Edge Driver."

Answer (score 1):

## But now it's 2023

As of 2023, there are a lot more ways to do this than when this question was posted:

1. Using a prebuilt container (easy but less useful)
2. Building your own Windows container (harder but works)
3. Building your own Windows inside of a Linux container (hardest)

Small note: To see if Edge is installed, your command in your question doesn't work on my local Windows 11 PRO machine. Try this one instead:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe").VersionInfo
```

### Using a prebuilt container

As mentioned by Krzysztof Cygan in another answer, you can get a prebuilt Windows container with MS Edge and MS EdgeDriver from here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-msedge-msedgedriver

Unfortunately, there are some downsides:

1. I could not for the life of me put my code on that machine and run a command line from it. It's meant to have your WebDriver/Selenium tests running on your computer and you just point your test harness to a given port to drive MS Edge. I have hundreds of tests and I want them each in their own container running with MS Edge inside, so this wasn't very useful for me.
2. The size of this docker image is 14.1GB

### Building your own Windows container

Using the directions [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/announcing-changes-to-windows-containers-image-composition-to/ba-p/3846615), I was able to create a Windows container that has a fully functional copy of Windows with Edge installed.

1. Save this in a file named `Dockerfile`:

```
#escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install Edge
RUN mkdir -p C:\temp -force; `
    # Get the bootstrapper to install edge
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; `
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108834&Channel=Stable&language=en' -OutFile 'C:\temp\MicrosoftEdgeBootstrapperX64.exe'; `
    # Start Edge bootstrapper
    $MSEDGE_BOOTSTRAPPER_EXE_ABSOLUTE_PATH = $(Resolve-Path 'C:\temp\MicrosoftEdgeBootstrapperX64.exe').Path; `
    Start-Process $MSEDGE_BOOTSTRAPPER_EXE_ABSOLUTE_PATH -ArgumentList @( '/silent', '/install') -Wait -NoNewWindow; `
    # Clean up
    Remove-Item $MSEDGE_BOOTSTRAPPER_EXE_ABSOLUTE_PATH -Force; `
    Remove-Item C:\temp -Force; `
    # Check Edge installation
    if(Test-Path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe") `
    { `
        Write-Host "Edge installed at default location!"; `
    } else { `
        Write-Host "Edge not installed at default location!"; `
        exit 1; `
    }

CMD cmd.exe
```

2. Run the following commands to build your own image (each of these commands takes a long time):

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022
docker build -f Dockerfile -t "server-with-edge:ltsc2022" .
```

3. Run your new docker image and play around:

```
docker run -it server-with-edge:ltsc2022 cmd.exe
```

[image: Showing a command line and that edge is there installed]

The size of this docker image is still pretty large, at 10.4GB.

### Building your own Windows inside of a Linux container (hardest)

This is a little bit crazy, but in a Linux docker instance, you can use virtualization to install a fresh copy of Windows, where you will then have Edge there by default. [Instructions are here](https://github.com/aerokube/windows-images).

I didn't try this, since I'm assuming this method must be very slow, especially since I'm running a Linux container in WSL in the first place. It also requires an additional Windows license key to install Windows, etc. I didn't want to deal with all of that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hopefully this will help some people out there. I don't know whether to mark this as the answer since I don't have the time to verify. In any case, I upvoted the answer :D !

Comment: HAHA. No worries. Like you said, this just gives people more avenues to consider when figuring this out.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there have Docker images for Chrome and Firefox, but not images for IE or Microsoft Edge. You could add a feedback from [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/304624-containers/suggestions/34081195-edge).

At present, as a provisional workaround, you could try to use Chrome and Firefox to do the selenium test. Please check the README at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

I will also try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. If I get any solution or a work around than I will try to provide you in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Using Chrome or Firefox isn't a workaround. Chrome and Firefox are two completely different browsers with completely different engines.

Comment: Since there is not images for IE or Microsoft Edge in Windows Container. If you still want to use Microsoft Edge to do the selenium test, you could try to create a Windows Virtual Machine to test it.

Comment: I know there isn't a Windowws Container image available for IE and Micrsoft Edge. I'm trying to create one myself. That's why I need to know where I can download Microsoft Edge.